# Is it possible to import react-aria's PressEvent?

Tags: reactjs, react-aria

The react-aria docs describe [a `PressEvent` and its properties](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/usePress.html). However I have not managed to find it anywhere in `@react-aria` node_modules directory to import it into my `.tsx` component. Has anyone managed this?

Comment: for now ive recreated it by examining and reproducing its properties but im really not comfortable with this tbbh

Answer (score 0):

You can import them like `import type { PressEvent } from '@react-types/shared';`